# Converting Predicate Logic Statement to Negation in English

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm working on some Predicate Logic and want to express a proposition in English into the negation.

The statement is: "Everyone who has not read a book is dumb"

My question is: Is the negation of this statement - "Some people who have read a book are dumb" or "Some people who have not read a book are dumb" or "Some people who have read a book are not dumb (i.e smart)"?

Would appreciate any explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither of those three. It is that there are some people who have not read a book but (and) who are not dumb.

In general, the negation of a statement like ‘All of *these* are like *that*’ is ‘there are some of *these* that are not like *that*.

Here, the *these* are the things about which you are saying something (the ‘subject term’), while the *that* is what you say about the *these*.

For example, the negation of ‘All crows are black’ would be that ‘some crows are not black’. (*these* are crows; *that* is being black)

In your case, the *these* are people who have not read a book, while the *that* is being dumb.

So, with the ‘Some of *these* are not *that*, you get the answer I provided above.

Finally, please don’t use ‘smart’ as the negation of dumb… someone can be neither dumb nor smart.

Comment: So to check my understanding, the statement "Everyone who has not been fed got sick" would be "Some people who have not been fed have not got sick"?

Comment: @LiteralJumpingAddition Exactly right!